# Installing tesseract 3.04 on lubuntu 18.04

Tags: tesseract, ubuntu-18.04

I want to install tesseract-ocr 3.04 on one of my Ubuntu/Lubuntu 18.04 test setups (which is running fine on our lubuntu16.04 test setups). If I simply install tesseract-ocr via 'sudo apt install tesseract-ocr' etc. it will install tesseract 4.0.0 beta.
With this I am seeing a lot of weird behavior and would like to run tesseract-ocr 3.04 with the same traineddata etc as it is running fine on our older test setups.

How can I force to install an older version of tesseract-ocr.

Thanks, Martin

Answer (score 1):

Download Tesseract 3.04 from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tesseract/3.04.01-6.

Then to install it in $HOME/local:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/
make
make install
```

I realise this post is quite old, so if you have found a better way please share your method.